# Basic hangman code-problem with changing the word after right answer

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code does not work properly. All I want is to make the word appear properly without any additional messages. What am I doing wrong? For simplicity, I just put one word ('weekend') so that I can easily check my code's mistakes every time I run it.

```
def hangman():
    j=0
    word='weekend'
    new_word=len(word)*'_ '
    while j<20:
        letter=input('Give a letter: ')
        for i in range(len(word)):
            if word[i]==letter and new_word[i]=='_':
                new_word=new_word.replace(new_word[i],letter)
        if new_word.replace(' ','')==word:
            print('You won!')
            break    
        j+=1
        print(new_word)

hangman()
```

Comment: So what do you want the code to do differently?

Comment: Nothing, I just want it to work, however when I run it, it does not work properly.

Comment: It probably has a logical mistake somewhere that I am unable to trace

Comment: This snippet has many bugs which can easily be seen by using `print` to show the value of `new_word`. For one thing, `replace()` will replace all the `_` instances.

Comment: @MichalisPapapetros check my answer and tell me if that worked for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you get all the letters replaced by the first letter the user inputs is because of the line:

```
new_word=new_word.replace(new_word[i],letter)
```

That happens because `new_word[i]` is equal to `'_'`, and `new_word` consists only of low dashes (besides the spaces, ofc) so all of the `'_'` will be replaced by the input letter.

This works:

#### Code (minimal change)

```
def hangman():
    j=0
    word='weekend'
    new_word=len(word)*'_'
    while j<20:
        letter=input('Give a letter: ')
        for i in range(len(word)):
            if word[i]==letter and new_word[i]=='_':
                new_word = new_word[:i] + letter + new_word[i+1:]
        if new_word.replace(' ','')==word:
            print('You won!')
            break
        j+=1
        print(new_word)

hangman()
```

The **only difference** between this and your code is the replacement of the afore mentioned line by:

```
new_word = new_word[:i] + letter + new_word[i+1:]
```

The code below is way more readable:

#### Code (major rework)

```
def hangman(word, tries):
    new_word = '_' * len(word)

    for _ in range(tries):
        if '_' not in new_word:
            return print('You won! :)')

        letter = input('Give a letter: ')

        for i, l in enumerate(word):
            if l is letter:
                new_word = new_word[:i] + letter + new_word[i+1:]

        print(new_word)

    print('You lost! :(')

hangman('weekend', 20)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. One more question: I want the user to see spaces between '_' , so that the number of letters of the word is clear. How can the code be changed, in order to make this possible without having bugs?

Answer (score 0):

```
def hangman():
    j=0
    word='weekend'
    new_word=len(word)*'_'
    while j<20:
        letter=input('Give a letter: ')
        print("letter =" + letter)
        for i in range(len(word)):
            if word[i]==letter and new_word[i]=='_':
                new_word = list(new_word)
                new_word[i] = letter
                new_word = ''.join(new_word)
        if new_word.replace(' ','')==word:
            print('You won!')
            break    
        j+=1
        print(new_word)

hangman()
```

This code does what you want to do. Mistakes in your original code:

```
`new_word=len(word)*'_ '`
```

(notice space in the end. This messed up indexing)

```
new_word=new_word.replace(new_word[i],letter)
```

This caused `new_word` to be replaced with `letter`! So it became `wwwwwww` (if someone had entered `w`)

```
        new_word = list(new_word)
        new_word[i] = letter
        new_word = ''.join(new_word)
```

Easy to understand way to replace a character at a particular index is to convert it into list and then replace with `letter` at that index. We convert list back to string later.

Comment: Thank you very much. One more question: I want the user to see spaces between '_' , so that the number of letters of the word is clear. How can the code be changed, in order to make this possible without having bugs?